# How do I configure a TenGig2/1 as Gig Uplink on a Cisco 4900M ( Module: ws-x4908-10g-rj45 )?

Tags: networking, port

### Scenario:

We were swapping out **Module 2** on a **Cisco 4900M** from a **20-Port Gig** to a **8-Port TenGig**, a **ws-x4908-10g-rj45** be precise.

The hot swap went fine and **TenGig2/1-8** `sho ip int bri` showed us the newly recognized ports, only that it wasn't just **TenGig2/1-8**, but rather **TenGig2/1-8** - and - **Gig2/9-16** (16 ports total).

```
4900M#sho ip interface  bri
Interface              IP-Address      OK? Method Status                Protocol
...
TenGigabitEthernet2/1  unassigned      YES unset  down                  down    
TenGigabitEthernet2/2  unassigned      YES unset  down                  down    
TenGigabitEthernet2/3  unassigned      YES unset  down                  down    
TenGigabitEthernet2/4  unassigned      YES unset  down                  down    
TenGigabitEthernet2/5  unassigned      YES unset  down                  down    
TenGigabitEthernet2/6  unassigned      YES unset  down                  down    
TenGigabitEthernet2/7  unassigned      YES unset  down                  down    
TenGigabitEthernet2/8  unassigned      YES unset  down                  down    
GigabitEthernet2/9     unassigned      YES unset  down                  down    
GigabitEthernet2/10    unassigned      YES unset  down                  down    
GigabitEthernet2/11    unassigned      YES unset  down                  down    
GigabitEthernet2/12    unassigned      YES unset  down                  down    
GigabitEthernet2/13    unassigned      YES unset  down                  down    
GigabitEthernet2/14    unassigned      YES unset  down                  down    
GigabitEthernet2/15    unassigned      YES unset  down                  down    
GigabitEthernet2/16    unassigned      YES unset  down                  down
...
```

---

### Question:

**How do I configure a TenGig2/1 as Gig Uplink?**

I immediately notices that connecting the **Uplink** cable did nothing, **no activity** on the port indicator.

Went ahead and configured `te2/1` anyway.

```
4900M(config)#int te2/1
4900M(config-if)#description Uplink to Router
4900M(config-if)#switchport access vlan 1
4900M(config-if)#switchport mode access
4900M(config-if)#l2protocol-tunnel cdp
4900M(config-if)#l2protocol-tunnel lldp
4900M(config-if)#l2protocol-tunnel stp
4900M(config-if)#l2protocol-tunnel vtp
4900M(config-if)#no cdp enable
4900M(config-if)#no shutdown
```

Still get no activity on the port...

```
4900M#sho int ten2/1 status
Port      Name                 Status       Vlan       Duplex  Speed Type
Te2/1     Uplink to Router     inactive     1            full   auto 10GBaseT
```

I figured that `gi2/9` corresponds to `te2/1` Gig functionality, since there is only 8 ports on this module, but it's displaying 16 total.

So, I configured `gi2/9` too.

```
4900M(config)#int gi2/9
4900M(config-if)#description Uplink to Router
4900M(config-if)#switchport access vlan 1
4900M(config-if)#switchport mode access
4900M(config-if)#l2protocol-tunnel cdp
4900M(config-if)#l2protocol-tunnel lldp
4900M(config-if)#l2protocol-tunnel stp
4900M(config-if)#l2protocol-tunnel vtp
4900M(config-if)#no cdp enable
4900M(config-if)#no shutdown
```

And again, no activity on that port. We've tried swapping out the cable and have even done a `reload` for good measure.

**How do I make that port an active Gig port for my uplink?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me some time, but I found the answer buried in documentation; where all the answers are, of course.

> **Short Answer:**
>
> ```
> 4900M#conf t
> 4900M#(config)#hw-module module 2 port-group 1 select gigabitethernet
> ```

---

### Explanation:

`sho hw-module module 2 port-group` will show you the `Active` port-group interfaces and their `Inactive` counterparts.

```
4900M#sho hw-module module 2 port-group
Module Port-group Active                         Inactive
-------------------------------------------------------------
   2        1     Te2/1-2                        Gi2/9-10                      
   2        2     Te2/3-4                        Gi2/11-12                     
   2        3     Te2/5-6                        Gi2/13-14                     
   2        4     Te2/7-8                        Gi2/15-16
```

So, the **module groups** two **ports together**, in this case it's **1-2**, **3-4**, **5-6**, and **7-8**. You can **select** the **port-group active interface** from **TenGig** to **Gig** through `hw-module module <#> port-group <#> select <port-group's int>`.

```
4900M#(config)#hw-module module 2 port-group 1 select ?
  gigabitethernet     Select this port-group's gigabit interfaces
  tengigabitethernet  Select this port-group's 10G interfaces
```

For our needs, I changed `module 2 port-group 1` selected interfaces from **TenGig** to **Gig**.

```
4900M#conf t
4900M#(config)#hw-module module 2 port-group 1 select gigabitethernet
```

Now I have an **active connection** for `gig2/9`.

```
4900M#sho int gi2/9 status
Port      Name               Status       Vlan       Duplex  Speed Type
Gi2/9     Uplink to Router   connected    1            full   1000 1000BaseT
```

And `sho hw-module module 2 port-group` shows the **updated** port-group's **active interfaces**:

```
4900M#sho hw-module module 2 port-group
Module Port-group Active                         Inactive
-------------------------------------------------------------
   2        1     Gi2/9-10                       Te2/1-2                       
   2        2     Te2/3-4                        Gi2/11-12                     
   2        3     Te2/5-6                        Gi2/13-14                     
   2        4     Te2/7-8                        Gi2/15-16
```

---

**IMPORTANT NOTE**: `Gi2/9-10` are both set to **Gig**, so if you are only intending to use one **Gig** port, then you will still have to scarify **two(2)** **TenGig** ports to do so.